# Geometry: parallelograms with diagonals

Tags: geometry

Draw parallelogram $RSTV$ so that the diagonals have the lengths $RT=5$ and $SV=4$. Which two angles of parallelogram $RSTV$ have the greater measure?

Comment: Start with a rectangle where RT = SV.  Now start deforming the rectangle such that RT>SV.  How are the angles changing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course those two angles which are facing the longer diagonal have greater measure, that means angle $RST$ and angle $TVR$.
[image]